# Reversed array with MQL4

Tags: low-latency, algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4, back-testing

With <kbd>**MetaTrader Terminal**</kbd> ( **`MQL4`** ), I try to have a reversed array, that I append ( prepend ) items to.

So, on every tick, **`myArray[0]`** becomes the 'newest' value, and the previous value shifts to **`myArray[1]`** and so on.

But its harder then it sounds.

I tried like this ->

```
       double myArray        = [];                        // GLOBAL Dynamic array
extern int    maxArrayLength = 50;                        // EXTERN iterable

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
bool   prependToReversedDoubleArray( double& theArray[], double value, int maxLength ) {

       int size = ArraySize( theArray );                 // LOCAL size
       ArraySetAsSeries(     theArray, false );          // Normalize the array ( left to right )
       ArrayResize(          theArray, size + 1 );       // Extend array length

       Alert( "test = ", size );

       theArray[size] = value;                           // Insert the new value
       ArraySetAsSeries(     theArray, true );           // Reverse the array again
       if ( ArraySize(       theArray ) > maxLength ) {
            ArrayResize(     theArray,    maxLength );
       }
       return( true );
}

prependToReversedDoubleArray( myArray, 0.1234, maxArrayLength );
```

Comment: And what is **The Question, Kev?**

Comment: [0] element always will be the newest.

Comment: [0] element may be the newest, the problem is, the **reversed array will not help** in given task **( ref. for details below )**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks for all the good intel! I learned a lot from the explanations :)

The problem I had was, *how to append values to the 'beginning' of a reversed array ( write to* `array[0]` *and shift the rest up )*.
It still not non-blocking and probably not the fastest way, but it works for now.

**Here is the solution, it also takes a 'maxLength' value, that keeps the array size as desired :)** :

```
int prependToReversedDoubleArray(  double &theArray[],
                                   double  value,
                                   int     maxLength
                                   )
{   int newSize = ArraySize( theArray ) + 1;
    ArraySetAsSeries( theArray, false );     // Normalize the array (left to right)
    ArrayResize(      theArray, newSize );   // Extend array length

    theArray[newSize-1] = value;             // Insert the new value

    ArraySetAsSeries( theArray, true );      // Reverse the array again

    if (  maxLength > 0
       && newSize   > maxLength )            // Check if the max length is reached
    {     newSize   = maxLength;
          ArrayResize( theArray, maxLength );
    }
    return( newSize );
}
```

Comment: Is this viable for say...10 arrays?  I need to have several arrays for this, as I am trying to translate a complex pine script (tradingview) script to MQL4.  Over there, every variable just magically works as a series, but it seems much more difficult in mql4.

Comment: This would make it quite simple, as long as it doesn't lag out when i'm constantly updating several arrays on every new candle

Answer (score 3):

```
for( int i = arraylength - 1; i >= 1; i-- ) {
    value[i] = value[i-1];
    }
value[0] = newValue;
```

Comment: While this is possible, one may kindly realise it is **computationally very inefficient** on growing scales of the ArraySize(). High performing tasks shall not block soft-real-time execution flow with uncontrollable mem-swaps and dumb cell-shifting per each tick arrival ( cadence in the order of [ms] ) -- where **both of these fatal drawbacks are out of your control and fortunately present in the proposed algorithmisation.** A better approach exists.

Comment: @user3666197.. I can already notice that when running multiple custom indicators in an EA, its not getting much faster.. So any info about efficient looping and calculating is more then welcome :)

Comment: Kev, the code-execution of **`Technical Indicator`**-s got the hardest hit from the *New*-**`MQL4.56789`**. It shares one single thread !!! ( yes, **ALL indicators are being executed under a limit of one shared thread ...!!!** ). One can imagine, what that makes with deep-recursive algorithms ( some of which were almost killing the old-MT4-model of code-execution ... ) .... so yes, **indicators can & DO BLOCK main Expert Advisor code-execution ...**

Comment: Ai, thats not good. I just posted another question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34355907/mql4-code-layout-for-big-ea) and I think its gonna be impossible.. I found some code that made it possible to use NodeJS as 'calculating' engine and communicating with MQL4.. You probably could clone each NodeJS instance and thus use multi-core. Have you ever tried something like that? I expect it to give a lot of troubles, but maybe there are more guys doing it?

Comment: Yes, we use MQL4 code, interconnected with many remote external actors ( while the motivation is not uniform, the technology is, which increases the ROI spent on learning curve and mastering the low-latency aspects of the distributed infrastructure ).

Answer (score 3):

---

### Intro:

Fortunately a **default** `MQL4` instrumentation for TimeSeries organisation **will not work on this scenario.**

Why?

`MQL4` TimeSeries ( reversed ) Arrays do get system-driven event-locked cell-index re-shuffling only on a current TimeFrame's `aNewBarEVENT`, not based on just every `anFxQuoteArrivalEVENT` ( as was asked in the O/P to shift / update `[0]` per each tick arrival *" ..., on every tick, "* ).

---

### How to make it work somehow?

A trivial **`for(){ shift 'em all / store new}`** kind of loops, proposed earlier, seems on a first glimpse, as a simple can-do hack.

The danger is a devil is hidden in details.

After some 100.000+ quotes, the array(s) grow to sizes a single memory-page will not hold the whole array + processing times for a dumb cell-shifting grows ( linearly ) in **`O(1)`**, but to such scales, which start to destroy an ability to be still as fast as being finally able to wait a few **`ms`** / **`us`** for next FOREX market events' arrival in a non-blocking mode, thus the <kbd>MetaTrader Terminal</kbd> inner architecture loses an ability to hold an illusion of a false-synchronicity with external events.

**`ArrayResize()`** is another hidden devil out there.

**In other words, such code will start "missing" events** ( will drop data ( which it will never see on arrival, as still shuffling data in the cell-shifting loop ) ).

---

### How to make it work fast & smart?

**0** ) Avoid memory-page swaps - stay In-RAM.

**1** ) Avoid any blocking step.

**2** ) Avoid a dumb cell-shuffling of any kind - alike `value[i] = value[i-1];`.

**3** ) Avoid any **`ArrayResize()`** on the fly.

Solution leads to a proxy in a form of a circular-buffer architecture with a distributed ( the only possible non-blocking help to an **`MT4`** `MQL4` code-execution with a rigid, user non-controllable, thread architecture )

This way `MQL4` code can contain a lightweight proxy-object ( internally a local, cache-alike managed ring buffer ) which can also seamlessly access literally limitless amounts of cell-data, stored and practically maintained in a remote process / a fast computing grid.

This is both **non-blocking** (ever) and **fast** and **smart** and **limitless**  <sub>( if your algo-trading needs that )</sub> .

Answer (score 0):

This can be done for optimal performance by creating your own dynamic Array class based on a linked list of pointers. You can define a custom operator `[]` to access its elements like you do with a normal array. This class can implement a `Prepend()` method that would be very fast as it would just have to perform a few operations with pointers and just one memory allocation.

However, such a class is not a simple thing to code, so depending on your goals, it might not be the best solution to your case.